# Magic of Conditional Branching (if, else if and else)

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

Not so long ago I encountered an example which shook my understanding of conditional branching. Let me explain. There are three buttons in Windows Forms application and I want to make access to this buttons different depending on the group (or groups) which user is a member of (Sales, Accountancy and HR). For example, if the user is a member of accountancy group that he (or she) should see the button of accountance but if he is a member of HR than he should see HR button. It works like this BUT what if the user is a member of several groups at once (for instance he is a member of accountancy and HR similtaneously)? In my logic this should allow user to see buttons accessible to both groups but actually he can only see the button of the latest group he had been added to.
So my question is the following: how can I achieve so that user being a member of several groups can see the buttons of this appropriate groups? I tried using only if statements and I tried using if and several else if statements but it doesn't works as I want. I thought about switch but it selects only one of many choices anyway and is not going to help me to solve my issue. I think that compound logical operators will look really ugly here. Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowsIdentity wid = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsPrincipal wp = new WindowsPrincipal(wid);

        const string salesRole = "Sales";
        const string accountancyRole = "Accountancy";
        const string managementRole = "HR";
        
        if (wp.IsInRole(salesRole))
        {
            SalesButton.Visible = true;
        }
        else if(wp.IsInRole(accountancyRole))
        {
            AccountancyButton.Visible = true;
        }
        else if(wp.IsInRole(managementRole))
        {
            ManagementButton.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions folks?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about `SalesButton.Visible = wp.IsInRole(salesRole);`, etc.? I don't see why splitting these into straight `if` statements without the `else` wouldn't have worked though.

Comment: You might have some logic that ensure only one button can be visible at a time, or your buttons might all be top of each other.  In either case that is nothing to suggest the given example is incorrect, at least assuming `wp.IsInRole` actually returns true for multiple roles.

Comment: Side note: `wid` needs a `using`

Comment: As a side note on UI design, it is usually better to disable buttons than to hide them.

Comment: @DavidG: depends, consider there are many roles and buttons but most users are only in  one, they always wonder why they have more buttons but they don't work(are disabled).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well that's why I said "usually". However, I'd still go with my point. Doesn't matter if the buttons are always disabled, it looks far better than blank space. Read any UI/UX guide and it will likely tell you the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `if`s:

```
SalesButton.Visible = wp.IsInRole(salesRole);
AccountancyButton.Visible = wp.IsInRole(accountancyRole);
ManagementButton.Visible = wp.IsInRole(managementRole);
```

On this way all buttons are visible where the user is in the appropriate role. It also ensures that all buttons are invisible where the user is not in role. Much simpler code that covers all cases.

Comment: This code looks better but unfortunately result is the same as before...

Comment: @Torrvic Are the states of these role changing WHILE the dialog is displayed?

Comment: @Torrvic: with "same as before" you say that still only one button gets visible and others stay invisible? Then the user is only in one role.

Comment: Worth noting that this code is doing something slightly different than OPs code. This one will set the `Visible` value regardless of whether the `IsInRole` returns true or not. If the buttons were already visible, this results in different functionality.

Comment: @DavidG: Yes, it fixes a possible bug in the original code that was not covered. It presumed that the initial state was invisible. This code ensures that tbe user sees only those buttons that he/she is allowed to see.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter only one button gets visible, others are invisible and I put initial condition of the buttons visability to false (Visible = false). So the buttons are in invisible state by default. I have Windows 7 Home Premium and using net localgroup cmd command to add users to groups. Tested user is definitely a member of several groups (checked it with net user command).

Comment: @MatthewWatson what do you mean sir? After I make any changing to code or add or delete user's role I log off because I know that users rights are correctly applied only after log off. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Torrvic: Have you used the debugger?

Comment: @TimSchmelter nope. Sorry I am a noob and I read nothing about debugger and don't know how to use it. I am just learning C#.

Comment: @Torrvic Yeah, that's what I meant.

Comment: @Torrvic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-absolute-beginners?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp (short: set a breakpoint in your code and then look in the quick watch window of the debugger what values each variable has. You can step through your code with F10/F11)

Answer (score 0):

Can't explain what happened but I after I tried debugging it started to work as intended for some cryptic reason. It is possible to close this case. Also for the sake of experimentation I activated builtin Administrator account and no matter what code I make it always see all buttons. But Ok. Nevermind...